# How to get rid of acceleration during bouncing ? (unity 2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I don't know if this is the correct therm, but I want to get rid of any kind of forces that could modify the speed of my object. Let me explain : the game is 2D top-down view and the character fires a bullet that bounces x amount of time, WITH CONSTANT SPEED. Everything works fine, but when the bullet bounces fast and many times, its speed increases.

Also, second problem: I have a rotating object and when the bullet hits it, its speed increases (which makes sense, but I would like to know if there is a way to delete this effect) .

[image]

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to solve my issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the material of the object for your first question (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) you need to set Bounciness to 1 so it will maintain dame speed. If you set it to 0 there will be no bounce and probably you have a value bigger than 1 and so it's increasing.

In the second case it's all about the forces involving. The object bouncing on the rotating one is adding a force to that one. If you want to keep the second one with same rotation you could rotate it with a transform.Rotate and remove a Rigidbody or set it to static

Comment: For the first question, the material already has bounciness set to one (you can see it in the first picture)

Comment: Not the bullet material, the objects that it hits. If there is no material than make sure to add a new one with bounciness of 1